# experiment with clip property in css

Tags: html, css

i am experimenting with the clip property in css.here inside an unordered list there will be four clipped images.First two in first row,second two in second row.But the images are not visible.why is it happening? how it can be fixed?
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yL4FQ/)

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
  body{
    overflow:hidden;
  }
  ul{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    display:table;
  }
  li{
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    position:relative;
  }
  li img{
    position:absolute;
    clip:rect(100px,200px,200px,300px);
  }

</style>
</head>
<body>
  <ul>
    <li><img src="cat1.jpg" ></li>
    <li><img src="cat2.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="cat3.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="cat4.jpg" ></li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove absolute position of the images, and add `overflow: hidden;` to the prent `li` element: Here is the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shekyb/yL4FQ/2/)

EDIT:

You shouldn't be using clip property to achieve what you need. One way to do it is to give `overflow: hidden` to the parent `li` element, keep the `position: absolute` of the `img` and give it appropriate `top` and `left` coordinates, instead of clip coordinates. So the effect we are using is to use the dimensions of parent `li` element to mask parts of the image that shouldn't be visible and to move the image to the right coordinates.

Here is the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shekyb/yL4FQ/3/):

Comment: thanks ..it works .but no matter the values inside the rect(....) the view remains the same here..:(

Comment: please explain exactly what you want to achieve, i don't think clip is what you want

Comment: i mean i want to show selected portion of the images only,not just the full image.thats the reason i want to use clip here.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code:

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/yL4FQ/1/)

```
li img{height:100px;width:100px;}
li img{clip:rect(100px,200px,200px,300px);}
```

Comment: thanks that works.but can i have a little explanation why this works ?and i thought css clip works only with absolute positioning which you have omitted.

Comment: what exactly you want to do with clip? because clip is not applied here, only resize of the images

Comment: my code was all about get it done using clip.not just do it anyway :)

Comment: try removing the clip property, result is the same